# table2array converts cell instead of numeric array MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am working on a `MATLAB` table datatype. 

*My data is as follows:*

```
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| table1 | % 1st table containing some numeric and characters |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| table2 | % 2nd table containing some numeric and characters |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| table3 | % 3rd table containing some numeric and characters |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| table4 | % 4th table containing some numeric and characters |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

where the rows for the tables are identical. I would like to extract the numeric part of the data in tables and make sure they are NOT the same. 
*I do as follows:*

```
data1 = table2array(table1(1:6,2:2500)); 
data2 = table2array(table2(1:6,2:2500)); 
data3 = table2array(table3(1:6,2:2500)); 
data4 = table2array(table4(1:6,2:2500));
```

However, table2array does NOT return a matrix **rather a cell datatype** for *data1,data2,...,data4* which makes the comparison part harder. Though the data are numeric, what is returned is cell datatype which is kind of strange for me. *I show the first and second column of table1 as an example:*

**Table1:**

```
+------+------------------+
| Info | mov_1            |
+------+------------------+
| 'F1' | 11.55            |
| 'F2' | 5.44e+6          |
| 'F3' | 1.5e+7           |
| 'F4' | 0.0011           |
| 'F5' | 0.0062           |
| 'F6' | 0.0513           |
| 'ID' | '0000000089.mp4' |
| 'nF' | 3252             |
| 'pT' | 1354.641         |
+------+------------------+
```

`table1` contains many columns similar to column 2. `table2 ... table4` have a similar structure to `table1`. As you can see only `ID` portion of *rownames* is string which is not included when I use *table1(1:6,2:2500)*.

How can I overcome this problem? Any cool ideas are appreciated in advance.

Comment: The data type is not numeric. Data types for tables are *per column* (therefore, per variable); if you have mixed data types for a variable the column will be cast as a cell array. Use [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html)

Comment: interesting! I have tried cell2mat() while sending this post, the problem is although the data look all numeric (i.e. cell arrays containing numeric values) , cell2mat() returns this error:  'Error using cell2mat (line 45)
All contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type.'

Comment: That doesn't help unless you also tell us *what* you used `cell2mat` on.

Comment: I simply used: cell2mat(data1) and got this error: 'Error using cell2mat (line 45) All contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type.'. Please note that ALL the data in data1 are numeric which is quite strange!

Comment: `Please note that ALL the data in data1 are numeric` Are you sure? Have you tried using a smaller subset of your data?

Comment: When using 'cell2mat(data1{:,1})' I receive the error 'Error using cell2mat
Too many input arguments.'
When using 'data1{:,1}' --> I receive 6 different discrete numeric values (not a vector).
When using '[data1{:,1}]' --> I receive a vector containing 6 numeric values
When using '[data1]' --> I receive a cell matrix identical to data1

Comment: Really the only answer is that you have non-numeric data even though you think you don't. I've created [a gist](https://gist.github.com/sco1/b730d5ed0db13f05c925) based on this question that functions as expected.

Comment: Thank you exacaza, I had this impression as well that's why It came very surprising to me. Anyway, I managed to solve the problem with function cell2num given here: http://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15306-cell2num